# Appium Testing tool unable to recognise element ID in ionic app

Tags: android, cordova, ionic2, appium, hybrid-mobile-app

We are using Appium Testing tool for automation testing for android application built in ionic but it is unable to recognise the ID and class names associated with DOM element:

[image]

But when we debug from chrome:inspect we were able to see all the ID and classes.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Appium Desktop application shows an Object Model for the native UI elements of the app: this includes native UI components within any Webviews, such as in a Cordova (Ionic) app. This is a pseudo-object model, designed to illustrate the hierarchy and properties of native UI elements.

However, when you connect a Chrome Devtools session to the Webview of your app, this is showing you the [HTML Object Model (DOM)](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp), which is not the same thing. This specifically models HTML elements so has HTML-specific concepts such as IDs and CSS classes which do translate to the native Object Model shown by Appium.

If you want to use Appium to run automated tests against a Cordova-based app, then you should use [wd](https://github.com/admc/wd) and [wd-bridge](https://github.com/sebv/wd-bridge) which provides a mechanism to allow Appium to communicate directly with the Webview. [This blog post](http://rolandoldengarm.com/index.php/2016/02/18/how-to-automatically-test-your-non-angular-cordova-or-ionic-app/) gives a great tutorial on how to setup such a test environment using Protractor/Jasmine.

You can then write Protractor tests which allow you to reference your app UI elements as HTML components, e.g.:

```
describe('Testing the app', function () {
  it('01. should have a header', function () {
    var header = element(by.id('header'));
    expect(header.getAttribute('class')).toContain('toolbar');
   });
});
```

Comment: Is there any specific steps that needs to be followed here, since id and class are empty on my application testing.

Comment: I've updated my answer with details of how you can implement automated testing for a Cordova-based app.